# MySQL selecting everything from one table with sums from 2 other tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

invoices: id, client

services: invioce_id, price

payments: invoice_id, amount

I'm wanting to select all the invoices with any services prices as amountDue and any payments amounts as amountPaid for each invoice.

So for example if I had the following rows:

invoices

```
id = 1, client = 232
id = 2, client = 535
```

services

```
invoice_id = 1, price = 5.00
invoice_id = 1, price = 10.00
invoice_id = 2, price = 20.00
```

payments

```
invoice_id = 1, amount = 7.00
invoice_id = 2, amount = 12.00
invoice_id = 2, amount = 8.00
```

I want the resulting query for all invoice rows to be something like:

invoices

```
id = 1, client = 232, amountDue = 15.00, amountPaid = 7.00
id = 2, client = 535, amountDue = 20.00, amountPaid = 20.00
```

I had a query like this:

```
SELECT invoices.*, 
sum(services.price) AS amountDue, 
sum(payments.amount) AS amountPaid 
FROM invoices 
LEFT JOIN services ON services.invoice = invoices.id 
LEFT JOIN payments ON invoices.id = payments.invoice 
GROUP BY invoices.id
```

but the resulting amountPaid was being multiplied by the number of services for each invoice.

Is there a way to pull all that data with one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two child tables with differing numbers of rows being returned in their respective joins. If you run your query without the grouping/summing, you end up with:

```
+------+-----------+-------+-----------+--------+
| id   | serviceid | price | paymentid | amount |
+------+-----------+-------+-----------+--------+
|    1 |         1 |  5.00 |         1 |   7.00 |
|    1 |         1 | 10.00 |         1 |   7.00 |
|    2 |         2 | 20.00 |         2 |  12.00 |
|    2 |         2 | 20.00 |         2 |   8.00 |
+------+-----------+-------+-----------+--------+
```

Notice how the payment amount $7 is duplicated for invoice #1, and the service price for invoice #2. MySQL is trying to fill in "holes" that your query structure produces, by duplicating values from whichever table has fewer rows.

For this kind of query to work, you need to use corelated subqueries, so that each subquery can do its own summing without being bound by the rowcount restrictions of the other tables:

```
select invoices.id,
   (select sum(price) from services where services.iid = invoices.id ) AS service_price,
   (select sum(amount) from payments where payments.iid = invoices.id) AS payment_amount
FROM invoices;
```

which produces

```
+------+---------------+----------------+
| id   | service_price | payment_amount |
+------+---------------+----------------+
|    1 |         15.00 |           7.00 |
|    2 |         20.00 |          20.00 |
+------+---------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Is it possible to take this one step further and only select invoices where payment_amount < service_amount?

Comment: sure, just add a `having` clause to the query: `... from invoices having payment_amount < service_amount`.